# Is it possible to use my existing HTML/CSS/JS with a move to Django?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I'm working on a full stack web application for a class, and originally was going to use AWS S3 for hosting, Dynamo as a database, Lambda for passing data to and from Dynamo, and Gateway API to connect the front and back end, but have had nothing but issues with AWS. As this is just a class project, nothing needs to be remotely hosted, and a classmate suggested Django to allow us to completely ditch AWS. After looking through a lot of the introductory stuff for Django, it looks like it could be the magic bullet we need. However, we already have dozens of hours sunk into our frontend HTML/CSS/Javascript, as well as some Bootstrap. My only reservation about making a complete dive for Django for handling our database and enabling us to run everything off localhost is that it seems to do EVERYTHING in Python, and I don't immediately see any way to integrate our existing frontend. Our frontend JS is intended to receive data from the database and do rudimentary calculations with it before providing it to the HTML page, and I'm also not sure how this would integrate with Django and SQLite.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  Please check [Which site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for various issues.

Comment: You have _drastically_ misunderstood what web frameworks do in Python. Django isn't a replacement for AWS, nor does it magically do all the HTML/JS/CSS work for you (though, no doubt, it can do parts)

Comment: May I ask what I've misunderstood? Unfortunately this is my first major web development project, so I apologize for my lack of awareness of resources. My reason for considering Django is that I thought it was able to host the HTML/CSS/JS on my local host, and that it provided easy integration with SQLite. We don't need hosting for remote access, just a proof of concept with a functional webapp that uses a database

Comment: You _may_ be mixing up the concepts of a "server" being a physical piece of kit and just a process that is listening on a port. AWS is sorta the former, Django (development server) is the latter. But Django isn't even a server. Just think of it, or Flask, coordinating the work; a request comes in, maybe Django will query your database, maybe it won't, but it will send some data back and render the template at the front end (which will still require your HTML/JS/CSS)

Comment: The database is separate from Django, but you can use the ORM to interact with it via models. That database will exist even if you then obliterated Django from your tools. The templates (e.g. the layout and styling of your site) _could_ also exist just fine without Django (I'm deliberately ignoring the template language); they just won't have any dynamic data in them. So Django is the middleman that links the two together. It is not a server.

Comment: So, you need a server in the sense of a physical piece of kit to run the programs, and you need a server in the sense of a process listening to incoming connections and delivering content. Django has a _development_ server for the latter case, but it shouldn't be used in that case because it's not production-ready (it will fail with lots of requests)

Comment: In my case, the site will never see the light of day outside of this semester, and it is likely that it will only ever need to be served over the local host. A lot of requests won't be going through, and it just needs to work for our 45 minute presentation and the hour or so the instructor will spend going over it. The professor also specified that the goal of the project was not cloud-focused, and simply wants a functional proof of concept, so having something over localhost only was acceptable. For this usecase, is Django appropriate for being a middleman between the frontend and database?

Comment: Yes, launch it on locahost

Answer (score 0):

- HTML: Most of it will be reused, but you will do some work of splitting it into templates and blocks if you plan to generate it on the server side, which is normal for Django.
- CSS: can be reused without change if you're careful with your HTML templates.
- Javascript: it very much depends on the way you structure your application. Likely much of it will require rework where it interacts with server side (like calling APIs), but most would work as-is where it only interacts with the client (like form validation, etc).

Please note that the architecture you're describing and a typical Django architecture differ quite much; do your research and write a toy project first. There is a number of good intros.

You will have to re-architect and rewrite all of your backend code. There seems to be Dynamo support if you stay with AWS, but everything around lambdas will likely go away, and you will deploy to normal AWS EC2 instances, or any other hosting provider if you want.

Remember: do the simplest thing that could possibly work. If in doubt, YAGNI.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I apologize if it's a bit of a dumb question, but I just started looking through Django today. The goal for the change is to ditch AWS entirely, use SQLite through Django as our database instead of Dynamo, (since all we used Lambda for was for communication to Dynamo, we can ditch that to) host it off of localhost, as this is just a proof of concept project

Comment: @nunzio: Sounds good! Also consider Flask, or even web.py,  plus SQLAlchemy or PonyORM. IDK what kind of a project do you have, but Django is somehow opinionated about the way to build things. Make sure it will help you because your design follows its expectations, not counteract you.